# Is there a way to tell why a maven dependency is at a certain version

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a spring boot app (which has a parent pom) and generally manages plenty of dependencies in terms of their version.

If I add this to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And list the dependencies it indicates that version is not the latest:

```
./mvnw dependency:list | grep dynamo
[INFO]    com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.125:compile
```

At time of writing the latest version is `1.11.838`, my current version is many months "out of date".

My IDE usually does a good job of showing me when a dependency is being "managed" e.g. by a parent pom. But in this case it doesn't indicate that this is the case.

My thinking is perhaps a transitive dependency is influencing this, but I'd like a more empirical way to find out.

Of course I could just add an explicit version element to the dependency or add an explicit dependency management element for this dependency. But my question is more academic in nature, I want to understand why maven determines that this is the right version to resolve.

Ideally what I'm trying to learn is what tooling or processes exist to "debug" this, e.g. a particular maven plugin which might help show how a version was resolved.

The result of: `mvn dependency:tree | grep -i dynamo | wc -l` is `1`. Which (I think) indicates that it's not appearing multiple times in transitive dependencies.

Comment: Which version of spring-boot do you use?

Comment: In this case `1.5.15.RELEASE`. If I do the same in spring boot `2.0.4.RELEASE` I get dynamo dependency `1.11.336` - but still not latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riddle solved, I was using a BOM `spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.SR4` which internally uses `spring-cloud-dependencies-parent:Edgware.SR4` which then uses `spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:1.2.3.RELEASE` which finally references `aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.125` as shown [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-dependencies/1.2.3.RELEASE/pom).

Answer (score 3):

Maven uses a "nearest wins" heuristic to resolve dependencies ([read more about Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)).

Here, you probably have two dependencies depending on the same artifact `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb`, but with different versions (`1.11.125` and another version).

When there is a conflict (see "Dependency mediation" in the guide I provided above), Maven resolves it by picking the "nearest" version from the root of your project. Below is an example :

```
             +----------------+
             |                |
             |  your project  |
             |                |
             +----+------+----+
                  |      |
            +-----+      +-----+
            |                  |
    +-------v------+    +------v-------+
    | dependency A |    | dependency B |
    +-------+------+    +------+-------+
            |                  |
            |                  |
+-----------v---------+        |
|    com.amazonaws    | +------v-------+
|aws-java-sdk-dynamodb| | dependency C |
|      1.11.125       | +------+-------+
+---------------------+        |
                               |
                     +---------v-----------+
                     |    com.amazonaws    |
                     |aws-java-sdk-dynamodb|
                     |       1.11.838      |
                     +---------------------+
```

Let's say your project depends on dependencies A and B, and those dependencies transitively depends on two different versions of `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb` (`1.11.125` and
`1.11.838`). Since version `1.11.125` is "nearer" from the root, then this version is picked. That's probably what happens in your case.

If you need to use this dependency in your own code, I recommend you to set explicitly the version of the artifact, and not relying on Maven choice.

### Additional info

Since Maven 2.0.9, if there is a conflict and no "nearest" artifact (in the previous example, if `B` have depended directly on `1.11.838` version), then the version picked depends if `A` is declared before or after `B` in your `pom.xml`. If `A` was declared first, then the version `1.11.125` would have been chosen.

Comment: Up voting for comprehensive information, however if i run this command: `mvn dependency:tree | grep -i dynamo | wc -l` the result is `1`. Unless I've misunderstood what this tree is showing me - if there were some type of conflicting transitive dependency wouldn't dynamo show up twice in the tree, rather than once?

Comment: @DavidGoate If you run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`, Maven will show you **all dependencies**, with messages like `omitted for conflict with x.x.x` for dependencies evicted because of versions conflicts. Thus, you should see what artifacts depends on `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb`, and the different versions.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, this is indeed interesting and showed me information that was new to me. The command `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep -i dynamo` shows me just `[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:jar:1.11.125:compile`, so no message about duplicates/conflicts (others in the list do but not dynamo) Thanks again for trying, but this still seems slightly unsolved to me as to how this specific dependency is being resolved to that version.

Comment: Hmm that's weird... Could you post your POM in your question, or at least reproduce a minimal POM leading to the same situation?

Comment: Thanks for your help, very valuable and led me to discover the underlying issue.

Comment: @David were you  able to figure out why duplicates/conflicts information was not show by mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep -i dynamo?